# how to convert pandas plot to OO Matplotlib bar chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plotting, bart

I am trying to convert pandas dataframe bar plot to matplotlib OO concept.

```
(npy_dataframe["Complaint Type"].value_counts()).head().plot(kind="bar")
```

this live perfectly working and generating bar chat attached

[image]

now this is my OO matplotlib trying to convert below what is wrong I am doing?

```
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure() # creates a figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
#print(plt.style.available)
plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")
# most frequest complaint
ax.bar(npy_dataframe["Complaint Type"].value_counts().head())
# add some label and title
ax.set(title="Most Common Compalints", ylabel="No of Complaints", xlabel="Complaint Type")

# Make the legebd visible
# ax.legend().set_visible(True)

# Add title to the figure
fig.suptitle("Compalints Analysis", fontsize=16, fontweight="bold")

# Add a mean line
ax.axhline(y=npy_dataframe["Complaint Type"].value_counts().head().mean(),linestyle="--")
```

Error is :-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2cbbdac7a93f> in <module>
      5 plt.style.use("seaborn-whitegrid")
      6 # most frequest complaint
----> 7 ax.bar(npy_dataframe["Complaint Type"].value_counts().head())
      8 # add some label and title
      9 ax.set(title="Most Common Compalints", ylabel="No of Complaints", xlabel="Complaint Type")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1446         if data is None:
-> 1447             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448 
   1449         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

I understand "Height" parameter is missing but how I compute this?.

Answer (score 1):

Only this line is solved the error

```
ax.bar(npy_dataframe["Complaint Type"].value_counts().head().keys(),npy_dataframe["Complaint Type"].value_counts().head())
```